# extending row number in windows function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the top 10 brands and article type on shopping page for etailer.
the logic I am using is as follows:

I am creating a table for both  ]using this logic below and storing top 10

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT shoppingpage_url,
         brand,
         COUNT(*) AS sp_count
  FROM TABLE name
  GROUP BY 1,
           2
)
 SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shoppingpage_url ORDER BY sp_count DESC) 
AS Top_10_flag
FROM cte
```

I am doing the same for article type and joining them both.

```
SELECT a.shoppingpage_url,
      a.top_10_flag,
   brand,
   article_type

FROM dev.top10_Brand a
LEFT JOIN dev.top10_Articletype b
     ON a.shoppingpage_url = b.shoppingpage_url
    AND a.Top_10_flag = b.Top_10_flag
```

The problem I am facing is for certain pages its just one brand but multiple article types.
I am missing the article types for the pages with brand counts Top_10_flag not equal to or lesser than Article type'Top_10_flag. 
how do I prevent this?

```
sample data
-- brand data table
shoppingpage_url, brand,sp_count,Top_10_flag
url1,brandd,5,1

url2,branda,17,1
url2,brandb,8,2
url2,brandc,4,3

url3,brande,5,1

-- article type table

shoppingpage_url, article_type,sp_count,Top_10_flag
url1,articletype1,5,1
url1,articletype2,5,1
url1,articletype3,5,1

url2,articletype12,17,1
url2,articletype3,8,2

url3,articletype23,5,1
url3,articletype2,5,1

-----
the result I am getting

shoppingpage_url,Top_10_flag, brand, article_type
url1,1,brandd,articletype1

url2,1,branda,articletype12
url2,2,brandb,articletype3
url2,3,brandc,

url3,1,brande,1articletype23
---------------------------
what i want


url1,1,brandd,articletype1
url1,2,,articletype2
url1,3,,articletype3


url2,1,branda,articletype12
url2,2,brandb,articletype3
url2,3,brandc,

url3,1,brande,1articletype23
url3,2,,1articletype2
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a `full join`?

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.shoppingpage_url, a.shoppingpage_url) as shoppingpage_url,
       COALESCE(b.top_10_flag, a.top_10_flag) as top_10_flag,
       b.brand, a.article_type
FROM dev.top10_Brand b FULL JOIN
     dev.top10_Articletype a
     ON a.shoppingpage_url = b.shoppingpage_url AND
        a.Top_10_flag = b.Top_10_flag
```

Comment: No a full join dint work since I have used top_10_flag also in my join condition.

Comment: I believe it's with the row number function, any way to populate it to default 10 even though there is just one row?